# how can i find the parameters of the methods in a webservice

Tags: android, web-services, parameters

I hava a webservice in this form:

```
<wsdl:message name="Service_GetPrice_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPrice"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Service_GetPrice_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPriceResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Service_GetNumber_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNumber"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Service_GetNumber_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNumberResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and i try to call this web service from an android application and i want to know every methode which parameters have so i can give them values.All the webservice is in this form and every methode has the same name for its parameters ("parameters").

In any other web service that i found every methode has a unique name for its parameters but not in this one and i am looking for a way to see what parameters does every methode take.

Please help me out cause i don't know almost nothing about webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please go through the basic concepts of WSDL structure.**

In the WSDL file, the methods are called operations and the messages can be used as the input and output for the operation.

Answer to your question - the parameters for the operation are defined in a message. In the above WSDL you have the parmaters coming from another namespace "tns:xxxx".

Better way to find out which parameters to send for a particular operation, if you really don't know about WSDL, is to use SOAP UI. Create a SOAP UI project and open a request, you can see all the parameters you need to send an operation.

FYI
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language

Comment: Thnaks.I will try it.

Comment: I try to use SOAP UI but it didn't manage to open the url of my web service.Nevertheless thanks for your help.

Comment: Show me the WSDL URL you are using??

Comment: its like this http://localhost:8000/Service?wsdl ...sorry but i can't give you the exactly URL.